# Is it possible to use object specific fields in a Global Action?

Tags: create-records, global-actions

I want users to be able to create a Case from a custom object Order__c using just a button and a pop-up form with some fields.

A Quick Action would be perfect, but alas, Case is not a related object of Order__c, so it is not possible to create a Quick Action that creates a Case object.

So I was looking at Global Actions. They get close, but still not close enough. For example, I would like to fill Case.AccountId automatically, but Global Actions do not have access to object fields.

This is the URL of a Global Action pop-up:

```
https://xyz.lightning.force.com/lightning/action/quick/Global.New_Delivery_case?objectApiName=Case&
context=RECORD_DETAIL&
recordId=a0B2600000CFo5dEAD&
backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOrder__c%2Fa0B2600000CFo5dEAD%2Fview
```

I was wondering if someone has managed to use `recordId` to somehow access fields of the current object, to use in the formulas of Case fields. Or something like that.

Comment: why not use a screen flow invoked by a quick action?

Comment: @cropredy Because that is a lot more work than a global/quick action. E.g. as this concerns a multi-language org, I must create custom labels for each of the entry fields, with its translations. And screen flow does not support picklists that are depending on record type, so I have to figure out a way to deal with that too. Quick/global actions are so much better, unfortunately they are not perfect as well.